# Total number of solutions of a completely blank sudoku

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we fill a $9\times 9$ matrix with digits from 1 to 9 so that all rows, all columns and all the nine $3\times3$ submatrices [obtained after partitioning the bigger matrix into nine $3\times3$ matrices] contain all the digits from 1 to 9? In other words, what is total number of solutions of a completely blank sudoku. I have been grappling with this problem for months without success. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type "total number of sudoku solutions" into Google then the first hit is Wikipedia's Sudoku article. Within it is a subsection called "[Enumerating the Sudoku 9×9 grid solutions directly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Enumerating_the_Sudoku_9.C3.979_grid_solutions_directly)". The answer seems to be 6,670,903,752,021,072,936,960.

You might like to read [this research article](http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/sudoku/sudoku.pdf).